# login session script in nodejs using express.io

Tags: node.js, socket.io, express.io

i want to create a login session script in nodejs.It should include username and password  which is already stored in a database.if the user enter the id which is not in the database then it should show invalid id else it should redirect to another html page.There are lot of frameworks for nodejs but i haven't got any scripts for login session in nodejs.So please anyone can me help by giving me a full script to do these task.

Comment: Your question isn't clear. How isn't passport (for example) solving that for you ?

Comment: i have to make a login session script using nodejs.but i dont knoe how to do that